# how to find integer solution to linear equation with rational numbers

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm sorry if I'm asking something incredibly easy, asked 100 times or if I express myself with the wrong words but I'm very new to the place and english is not my language and mathematical terms are not exactly everyday talk.

my equation is $(15625/1024)*x + (2101/256) = y$ and I have to find the smallest pair of x and y with both numbers positive integers.
I'm quite frustrated because when i started it seemed a really easy problem but i couldn't figure it out.

In the end using alternative (not very mathematical) ways i found out the solution should be x=204, y=3121 but i was wondering what is the correct method to find the result?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The given equation can be converted to the following:
$$15625x+8404=1024y$$
We can rewrite this as
$$15625x-1024y=8404$$

Now this problem has been converted to that of linear combination of integers. This means now you can use Euclid's algorithm for computing GCD to get the numbers you are looking for.

I would recommend you to look into https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/cryptography/modarithmetic/a/the-euclidean-algorithm.

Comment: But i thought that since $15625 = 5^6$ and the other two numbers are not dividable by 5 they don't have a gcd, therefore there should be no solution with integer numbers. obviously that is wrong so, even I feel incredibly stupid asking, what do I do?

Comment: @Skipjack3 it doesn't matter that other two numbers are not divisible by $5$. Moreover GCD of the two numbers definitely exist. Think $5-3=2$, here also other two numbers are not divisible by $5$ but definitely this equation is true.